# Retrieve DataExtension for TriggeredSendDefinition

Tags: marketing-cloud

How to retrieve DataExtension object associated with TriggeredSendDefinition ? I have been using the following code but its saying "Error: The Request Property(s) SendSourceDataExtension.Name do not match with the fields of TriggeredSendDefinition retrieve"

```
        RetrieveRequest rr = new RetrieveRequest
        {
            ObjectType = "TriggeredSendDefinition",
            Properties = new string[] { "CustomerKey", "Name", "SendSourceDataExtension.Name"},
            ClientIDs = new[] { clientId }
        };
        SimpleFilterPart sfp = new SimpleFilterPart
        {
            Property = "CustomerKey",
            SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.equals,
            Value = new string[] { "expiry_notice" }
        };

        rr.Filter = sfp;

        status = soapClient.Retrieve(rr, out requestID, out results);

        foreach (TriggeredSendDefinition tsd in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tsd.CustomerKey + " " + tsd.SendSourceDataExtension.Name);
        }
```

I have also tried to remove the Properties line from RetrieveRequest (hoping it will retrieve everything for the TriggeredSend) but it does not seem to work.

Is there a workaround to retrieve which data extension is associated with the TriggeredSendDefinition ?

Comment: Were you able to get the `SendSourceDataExtension` to display at all?

Comment: No. Even if I just put SendSourceDataExtension  in Properties, it is not working.

Comment: Let me know if this answers the question for you.

Answer (score 2):

After running a `describe` method on the `TriggeredSendDefinition` object it returned with this:

```
<Properties>
  <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
  <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
  <Name>SendSourceDataExtension</Name>
  <DataType>DataExtension</DataType>
  <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
  <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
</Properties>
```

Looks like that it is not retrievable.

**Sample Describe Call**

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <Header>  
      <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">AUTH TOKEN</fueloauth>
   </Header> 
   <Body>
      <DefinitionRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <DescribeRequests>
            <ObjectDefinitionRequest>
               <ObjectType>TriggeredSendDefinition</ObjectType>
            </ObjectDefinitionRequest>
         </DescribeRequests>
      </DefinitionRequestMsg>
   </Body>
</Envelope>
```